# Is there a network analysis tool built into Orange?

Tags: orange

I am interested in a canned or built-in network analysis tool.  Wondering if this is possible with Orange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Networks add-on for Orange data mining suite](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-network) should help you. If you are open to using other solutions, I would recommend [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) Python library.